# ¿Cómo selecciono distintas columnas no contiguas para hacer una tabla dinámica?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando con tablas dinámicas de Google Spreadsheets. Me funciona bien y estoy sacando datos interesantes, básicamente gracias a lo aprendido en [¿Cómo veo cuál es el valor más común (moda) de una columna?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/289190/83).

En esta ocasión tengo la siguiente tabla de libros leídos

```
 A  |  B    |   C   |  D   |   E    |   F
año | libro | autor | nota | idioma | país autor
```

Con entradas del tipo

```
 A   |  B               |   C         | D | E   |   F
-------------------------------------------------------------
2004 | Hamlet           | Shakespeare | 8 | ES  | Reino Unido
2005 | Crimen y castigo | Dostoievski | 9 | CAT | Rusia
2011 | Dersu Uzala      | Arseniev    | 8 | EN  | Rusia
```

Ahora quiero crear una tabla dinámica que agregue los países de los que proviene el autor, me diga cuántos libros he leído de cada país y qué media de notas tiene.

En este caso específico saldría algo así como:

```
país        | #libros | nota media
----------------------------------
Rusia       |    2    |     8,5
Reino Unido |    1    |     8
```

He sido capaz de hacer la primera parte, la de:

```
país        | #libros
---------------------
Rusia       |    2
Reino Unido |    1
```

Con una tabla dinámica en la que simplemente elijo la columna `F:F`. Sin embargo, para hacer la media de las notas también necesito la columna `D` y no sé cómo convertir `F:F` en algo así como `D:D;F:F`. ¿Cuál sería la forma?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo, causa o razón :P por el cual tienes que seleccionar columnas no contiguas para generar la tabla dinámica (TD)? ¿Acaso tu caso real tiene demasiadas columnas que se hace difícil encontrar la columna necesaria en algunos de los selectores de los elementos de la TD como Filas, Columnas, Valores, Filtros? ¿Acaso te preocupa  o has encontrado un problema sobre el desempeño de la hoja de cálculo o TD? ¿Tienes algún caso en el que los datos fuente sean muy grandes?

Comment: @Rubén más que nada lo hacía pensando en optimizar la recolección de datos. Si pienso en MySQL, allí traigo las columnas que me interesan, no otras. Aquí pensé en hacer lo mismo: ¿para qué coger nombre de autor o título del libro si no voy a hacer nada con ellos? No sé si internamente seleccionar menos columnas ayuda a que todo sea más eficiente.

Comment: Las tablas dinámicas son otra cosa, pero quizás e ayude ver la especificación del intervalo fuente como la cláusula "from" en lugar de verlo como la cláusula "select"

Comment: En cuando a la parte de la eficiencia es un tema muy extenso. Una "curiosidad": las tablas dinámicas de Excel, tienen la opción de guardar en el trasfondo una copia de los datos fuente, esto aumenta el tamaño del archivo de Excel pero agiliza la configuración de la misma, pero en el en el caso de las hojas de cálculo de Google no existe esta opción, así como tampoco se registra su tamaño en términos de bites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene sentido seleccionar columnas no contiguas cuando la fuente de datos es una tabla (conjunto de datos formado por columnas y filas contiguas). La recomendación es KISS (keep it super simple, mantenlo super sencillo)

1. Prepara los datos. En este caso, agrega los encabezados en la primera fila y debajo de estos los valores
2. Selecciona una celda de tu tabla de datos, en este caso cualquiera del intervalo `A1:F4`
3. Haz clic en el menú Datos > Tabla Dinámica
4. Selecciona el destino (nueva hoja, misma hoja, especifica la celda origen para la tabla dinámica), digamos que `A6`
5. Configura tu tabla dinámica

   - En filas, agrega `país autor`
   - En valores, agrega libro, especifica `COUNTA`
   - Nuevamente en valores, agrega `nota`, especifica `AVERAGE`
6. Personaliza los encabezados,

   1. haz clic en `B6` y edita el valor de la celda
   2. haz clic en `C6` y edita el valor de la celda
7. El resultado debe ser similar a lo siguiente:

   [image]

Comment: ¡Hola! Me surgió una duda nueva y publiqué en SO: [How can I have multiple pivot tables in same sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62197365/1983854). Si quieres publico en SOes también.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Gracias por avisar :)  En lo personal me gustaría ver más preguntas sobre el tema por aquí, pero fuera de lo que ya sabes no se me ocurren más argumentos.

Comment: Pues cuando tenga un rato la publico aquí, muchas gracias Rubén. (En SO publico pocas preguntas y me apetecía probar también allí)

Comment: Pues ahora puse una recompensa aquí en SOes a [¿Cómo puedo crear un campo autoincremental en una tabla dinámica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/362920/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Gracias por el aviso :)

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tienes que seleccionar toda la información para meterla en la tabla. Suponiendo que tienes:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo seleccionas y pinchas en `Datos > Tabla dinamica` con los datos de `'Hoja 1'!A1:F4`

En la siguiente imagen pincharías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
1º  Filas > Añadir > pais autor

2º Valores > Añadir > libro

3º Valores > Añadir > nota
```

En esta última tendrías que cambiar `SUM` por `AVERAGE`

Y ya tendrías:

[image: ![![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres cambiar el nombre de los encabezados, pinchas uno de ellos y escribes lo que quieras poner en la barra superior (varás que ya pone `COUNTA de libro` o `AVERAGE de nota`, segun el que hayas seleccionado).

Comment: Aaah ¿pero no es posible seleccionar solamente algunas columnas? Porque por ejemplo autor y título son innecesarias.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, no se puede (igual alguno viene y dice como se hace, pero creo que no...), de todas formas aunque sean innecesarias, solamente las estás incluyendo en el rango de datos, no significa que las estés 'usando'

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Cuál sería la ventaja de seleccionar solamente algunas columnas? ¿Cuál es el problema de que se incluyan en la referencia  a la fuente de datos columnas innecesarias ?