# ¿Cómo ordeno una tabla dinámica según el valor de dos columnas calculadas dinámicamente?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

Estoy trabajando con una hoja de cálculo donde almaceno los libros que he leído. Tal y como expliqué en [¿Cómo selecciono distintas columnas no contiguas para hacer una tabla dinámica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/294628/83), la estructura es del tipo:

En esta ocasión tengo la siguiente tabla de libros leídos

```
 A  |  B    |   C   |  D   |   E    |   F
año | libro | autor | nota | idioma | país autor
```

Con entradas del tipo

```
 A   |  B                 |   C         | D | E   |   F
-------------------------------------------------------------
2004 | Hamlet             | Shakespeare | 8 | ES  | Reino Unido
2005 | Crimen y castigo   | Dostoievski | 9 | CAT | Rusia
2007 | El mundo es ansí   | Baroja      | 8 | ES  | España
2011 | Dersu Uzala        | Arseniev    | 8 | EN  | Rusia 
2015 | Hermanos Karamazov | Dostoievski | 8 | ES  | Rusia
2019 | ... Shanti Andía   | Baroja      | 7 | ES  | España
```

Tengo unas cuantas tablas dinámicas (ahora que descubrí cómo se hacen, lo estoy aprovechando mucho :P) y una de ellas lo que hace es agrupar por autores y ordenar por el número de libros que he leído de cada uno.

Definí:

FILAS

- `autor` (columna C) con

  - ordena: Descendiente por `COUNT de autor`

VALORES DE ORIENTACIÓN

- `autor`

  - resume por: `COUNT`
  - muestra como `Predeterminado`
- `nota`

  - resume por: `AVERAGE`
  - muestra como `Predeterminado`

Así, dados los datos anteriores me sale algo así como:

```
 autor      | COUNT de autor | AVERAGE de nota
-------------------------------------------------------------
Baroja      |        2       | 7,5
Dostoievski |        2       | 8,5
Shakespeare |        1       | 8
Arseniev    |        1       | 8
```

Está bien porque ordena de más libros leídos a menos. Sin embargo, me gustaría ordenar en segundo término por el `AVERAGE de nota`. Es decir, que a igualdad de `COUNT de autor` tome en consideración `AVERAGE de nota` para decidir el orden, yendo de mayor a menor. En el caso del ejemplo, Dostoievski iría por delante de Baroja (8,5 > 7).

He estado mirando distintas opciones pero no encontré cómo hacerlo sin que me incluya una columna extra.

Comment: Me parece que en las hojas de cálculo de Google no es posible.

Comment: @Rubén caramba! Preguntaré en [SO] a ver si hay algún truco para ello. Muchas gracias

Comment: En tu pregunta dices "no encontré cómo hacerlo sin que me incluya una columna extra" entendí que no querías trucos :)

Comment: Por cierto, no te olvides de enviar tu "feature request" directamente a Google usando "Google Feedback".

Comment: @Rubén jaja, cierto. No sabía que hubiera ese "feature request". Voy a ver si funciona o es más bien como Meta :D

Comment: "Funciona mejor" cuando "millones" de usuarios piden lo mismo ;) La semana pasada estuve en un evento para expertos de producto. Se nos insiste mucho en usar Google Feedback incluso para las herramientas que nos dan en los foros oficiales.

Comment: Algunas cosas se "resuelven" muy rápido, otras no.

Comment: Lo he planteado en SO: [Can I order a pivot table using a second condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456053/1983854)

Comment: @Rubén (-perdón si la notificación es molesta!!) ... parecías interesado en una
posible respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría hacer sin agregar una columna extra *en la tabla de origen*, pero ... implica agregar una columna extra *en la tabla dinámica*.

Dentro de los **Valores** de la tabla, se puede añadir un `Campo calculado`.

> [image: Valores de TD]

Con una fórmula que sirva para ordenar según un criterio que combine más de 1 campo. Por ejemplo:

```
=COUNTA(Autor) * 100 + AVERAGE(Puntaje)
```

- Es **importante** seleccionar que `Sumar por` sea `Personalizado`. Así, toma el valor final de la fórmula (y no va sumando valores por cada ítem del origen).

Y luego de crear ese campo calculado, vamos a las **Filas** y elegimos ese nuevo campo para que ordene:

> [image: Orden de filas por 2 columnas]

---

---

Por supuesto, tiene la contra de que agrega una columna a la tabla dinámica (se le puede cambiar el nombre "Campo calculado 1" por algo como "Orden")

> [image: Resultado]

aunque podríamos ocultar toda esa columna y olvidarnos del tema.

> [image: con columna oculta]

---

**Nota**: esto mismo se podría hacer con arrayformulas o con un query que no generen esa columna extra, todas opciones que no usan tablas dinámicas. Entiendo que no es la idea acá.

Comment: ¡Excelente! Gran idea, gran explicación y resultado exactamente como deseaba. Formulé la pregunta [también en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456053/1983854), por si quieres publicar la respuesta también allí.