# ¿Cómo puedo crear un campo autoincremental en una tabla dinámica?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

Tengo una hoja de cálculo con los resultados de gente corriendo en un circuito. He creado una tabla dinámica que me coge el resultado y me ordena a la gente, cuyo nombre está en la columna A, según el tiempo que hicieron, que aparece en la columna B.

Entonces la tabla dinámica ordena perfectamente y me es muy útil. Para que quede aún mejor, me gustaría que mostrar al lado la posición de cada persona en esa clasificación. Es decir, que según los filtros que tengo aparezca al lado de la persona un 1, 2, 3... y así sucesivamente.

Mirando las opciones de campos a añadir, veo que puedo añadir:

- las columnas que ya tengo, que no interesa
- un valor calculado a partir de lo que ya tengo, como suma, desviación, media... pero no ayuda
- campos calculados, así en general

Esta última parte, la de *campos calculados*, resulta interesante. Sin embargo, mirando la documentación de Google Sheets no veo que haya un campo "AUTO INCREMENT" o similar, y [las opciones que veo al respecto](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/15449/136408) hablan de triggers y demás.

Así pues: ¿existe alguna manera a través de tabla dinámica directamente?

Más datos en [How can I have multiple pivot tables in same sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62197365/1983854), así como muestra en https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MVX3tp6GIqVX6hTyk6TsCxV7YngiMpi7E8oSxa7a9ck/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Haz probado ArrayFormula aquí encontré un ejemplo tal vez te sirva.
[ArrayFormula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BX4wfjSb6mGdsvH43pyraNOezDhvz81aHKCsIoFpG8E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Mmmm no veo cómo me sirve ni veo explicación alguna

Comment: Mi primera impresión es que no es posible usar la función de tabla dinámica (pivot table) en la hoja de cálculo de Google por sí sola para agregar un número auto incremental. Por  lo anterior yo intentaría otras cosas. En fin, ¿estás dispuesto agregar columnas auxiliares a los datos fuentes y/o al resultado de la tabla dinámica? ¿Has explorado el uso de funciones como `ROW`,`RANK`, entre otras?

Comment: Relacionado [Spreadsheet pivot table with ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51099004/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén no he usado RANK ni ROW y sí, estoy dispuesto a agregar columnas auxiliares. Dicho lo cual, si la opción de generar un script es más recomendable, estaré encantado de aprender

Comment: Pues bienvenido al maravilloso mundo de ... ups, no se me ocurre ningún nombre, en fin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estamos ante el caso del [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21) y, por lo mismo, daré una respuesta que resuelve lo que pienso que es tu problema, y no necesariamente sigue el camino de la solución que estás intentando, aunque si te lo entrega en la tabla dinámica, como has explicado en la pregunta.

## Mis suposiciones

- Que tienes una *tabla* simple con datos, según has explicado en la pregunta, que luce como esta: [image: Tabla base con nombres y tiempos]
- Que con ella has construido una tabla dinámica que tiene agregado el campo `Nombre` como *Filas* de la tabla y en *Datos* cualquier alguna función que haga sentido sobre el campo `Tiempo` (en mi caso he seleccionado `MIN`, pero dado que solo hay una fila con cada nombre, da lo mismo `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVERAGE`) y que ordenas la tabla por esta columna, más o menos como esto: [image: Tabla dinámica actual ordenada por tiempos]
- Lo que quieres lograr es una nueva columna que te muestre cual es la posición de cada persona en los resultados, de manera dinámica (que se ajuste automáticamente tal como lo hace el resto de la tabla, cuando cambian los tiempos), más o menos como esto: [image: Resultado esperado con columna de posición]

## La solución

Para lograr este resultado, y con ello resolver tu pregunta, en lugar de añadir esta información directamente en la tabla dinámica, lo que he hecho es agregar una columna `Posición` a la tabla de datos, valiéndome de la función [`RANK()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094098?hl=es), que sirve justamente para obtener la *posición* de un valor entre un conjunto de valores: [image: Tabla de base con columna de posición]

Finalmente, he añadido el `MIN` de esta columna en la parte de datos de la tabla dinámica, para que se muestre así: [image: Tabla dinámica con posición]

He dejado todo en [esta hoja de google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lcToooMauOvxe4lYWTNpkbfdR0wrkr0ezOtaA_NBcBE/edit?usp=sharing) para que se pueda directamente echarle un vistazo.

Comment: Qué bueno, diste en el clavo. Mi hoja de cálculo es como describes, si bien con el matiz que un mismo nombre puede tener distintas entradas, pero eso sería ya para otra pregunta. Gracias por explicar el comando `RANK()`, que para este caso resuelve el problema.

Comment: Hombre, me alegra ser de ayuda, sobre todo a alguien tan apreciado en la comunidad. Un saludo fedorqui, que estés bien!

Answer (score 1):

Mi primera impresión es que no es posible usar la función de tabla dinámica (pivot table) en la hoja de cálculo de Google por sí sola para agregar un número auto incremental. Por lo anterior yo intentaría otras cosas.

En las hojas de cálculo de Google, la forma más sencilla de agregar un número *autoincremental* es quizás creando una serie, quizás ya sabes, en `A1` escribes `1`, en `A2`, escribes `2`, en `A3`, escribes `3`, seleccionas las tres celdas, haces clic en la esquina inferior derecha y arrastras.

Otra forma es usar la función `ROW`; en `B1` escribes `=ROW(A1:A10)` luego presionas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, sueltas y presionas <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Voilà!

Quizás usar *Google Apps Script*, siendo programador quizás te resulte más cómodo pues es cosa de aprender a usar un *IDE* web muy básico, aprender de "Spreadsheet Service" y lo básico de JavaScript para el manejo de vectores y matrices (Array y Array anidados, particularmente bidimensionales.

Guía oficial [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). En el mismo sitio se encuentran "quickstarts" y codelabs